# Page redirect in Angular/MVC app

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a button in my view that I need to redirect me to a page to edit the element it is associated with.

Here is the button - pretty straight forward.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="edit(x.TemplateStepID)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>
```

Here is the function in my angular controller.

```
$scope.edit = function (e) {                
            TemplateService.editTemplateStep(e)
            .success(function (data) {

            })
            .error(function (error) {

            });
        };
```

and the function in the app.factory:

```
TemplateService.editTemplateStep = function (stepID) {
            alert(stepID);                
            return $http.get('@Url.Action("EditTemplateStep", "TemplateStep")', stepID);
        }
```

Now I can get the data to pass all the way to the editTemplateStep function. But I cannot figure out how to get that info (stepID) to get passed to an MVC controller function so I can redirect to the edit page of the element the button is associated with.

New to Angular and MVC for that matter.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Mixing angular with MVC like that is going to create a mess of an application.  Why not use something like ngRoute (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example) and keep it all in angular?

Comment: I might not be understanding ngRoute fully.  But it seems that it does not completely do what I need.  For this view my url is something like this: lhttp://localhost:23455/Template/EditTemplate/27, but after the click I need it to redirect to http://localhost:23455/TemplateStep/EditTemplateStep/{id of template step}.  If that makes any sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the `$scope.edit`'s parameter and use it when you call the reDirect function:

```
$scope.reDirect(stepId, data) {
   //do the redirect
};    
$scope.edit = function (e) {
     var stepId = e;                
     TemplateService.editTemplateStep(e)
         .success(function (data) {
             //Call the redirect function
             $scope.reDirect(stepId, data);
         })
         .error(function (error) {

         });
    };
```

**Update: deprecation notice**

The `.success` and `.error` methods of the `$http` service have been deprecated. Instead use the `.then` and `.catch` methods.

```
$scope.edit = function (e) {
     var stepId = e;                
     TemplateService.editTemplateStep(e)
         .then (function (result) {
             //Call the redirect function
             $scope.reDirect(stepId, result.data);
         })
         .catch (function (error) {
             //log error
         });
    };
```

Notice that `.then` returns data differently than the `.success` method.

For more information on the deprecation of `.success`, see [AngularJS $http service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).